# How to set img src to php session in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session

I have created a program in php. In this program, i want to preview upoaded image before submit form in php. Here is my code for html form.

```
<form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Upload your closeup photo</label>
    <input onchange="readURL(this);" type="file" name="myfile"/>
</form> 

<img alt="Image Display Here" id="test" src="assets/images/nopic.jpg" height="500px" width="450px" style="display:block;"/>

 <form  action = "matrimony_action.php" method="post" name = "matrimony" onsubmit="return validate()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input class="btn btn-action pull-left" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submitted8" id="submitted8">
 </form>
```

This is my javascript function code called on 'input type file'

```
function readURL(input) 
{
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) 
        {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) 
            {
                $('#test').attr('src', e.target.result);
                //$("#test").css("display", "block");
                $('#test').css({"display":"block"});
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
        $.session.set("img", "hello"); // i am not sure about this statement.
}
```

and at the php file. i had written following lines.

```
<?php
   $photo1 =  $_SESSION["img"];
   echo $photo1;
?>
```

Image is previewing better before submitting form. at the last i am getting error "Undefined index: img".
please help me.

Comment: You could not call `$.session.set("img", "hello");` inside JS code.

Comment: thanks for replying. then tell me how can i do this?

Comment: It’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking, is the image shown on `test` input? what you expected from `echo $photo1;`  to show  (src of img or name ...)?

Comment: after uploading, image is shown perfectly in test input. after this. i want to store it in mysql database by submitting form "matrimony".

Comment: you can submit your form normally to php .

Comment: Sorry @Drudge.. it is not working. it says input 'myfile' not found.

Comment: you can use only one form instead of two

Comment: how can i set session of this img src?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use just one form so the `myfile` will be sent also to `matrimony_action.php`, e.g :

```
<form  action = "matrimony_action.php" method="post" name = "matrimony" onsubmit="return validate()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Upload your closeup photo</label>
    <input onchange="readURL(this);" type="file" name="myfile"/>

    <input class="btn btn-action pull-left" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submitted8" id="submitted8">
</form>

<img alt="Image Display Here" id="test" src="assets/images/nopic.jpg" height="500px" width="450px" style="display:block;"/>
```

**NOTE :** You don't need session since the img file will be submited with form.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks.. can i use this statement outside form tag?                                '<img alt="Image Display Here" id="test" src="assets/images/nopic.jpg" height="500px" width="450px" style="display:block;"/>'